# Выборка SQl с условием статуса

Tags: php, sql

друзья помогите сформировать  выборку (если конечно это реально),
нужно сделать фильтрацию по датам
проблема в том что есть несколько типов дат (дата создания,дата завершения и т.д ) в зависимости от статуса заказа фильтровать нужную дату к примеру:
если статус 1 (создан) то фильтровать по дате создания если статус 2 (завершен) то фильтровать по дате завершения?

Comment: `status =1 and date1 = '...' OR status=2 and date2= '...'` ?

Comment: супер, работает ,спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Предикат, предложенный Teran'ом, является более академически правильным, но если условие ... достаточно сложное, то его дублирование два раза может привести к ошибке при будущих правках.

Есть еще один вариант.

```
CASE status WHEN 1 THEN date1 WHEN 2 THEN date2 END = ...
```

Также это выражение можно вывести столбцом пользователю.